# Calendar app want to sync with the ios calendar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I recently sync my calendar app with ios calendar which i am sending only Title, Location, StartDate, EndDate. Which is not enough for me. How can i sent Repeat, Alert All the details that required in ios calendar. Is this possible to Sent all the event Details to ios calendar.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLZyD.jpg)

Here in this image i am sending Title,Location,StartDate, EndDate.. But I need to add Repeat, Alert, Notes all Which i want to sync with Ios Calendar.. Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EKCalendarItem you are utilizing to add the initial details has properties and methods that can accomplish your alerts, repetitions and notes:

```
EKCalendarItem().addAlarm(EKAlarm.init(NSDate()))

EKCalendarItem().notes = "My note text"

EKCalendarItem().addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule.init())
```

Note: the above are sudo code but are pretty straightforward. The EKRecurrenceRule has a more complicated init method with the signature:

```
init(recurrenceWithFrequency type: EKRecurrenceFrequency,
                interval interval: Int,
                     end end: EKRecurrenceEnd?)
```

Please consult the Apple docs for more info [Calendar Event Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKCalendarItem/addRecurrenceRule:)